# Using MapView in Xamarin.Android without fragment

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, android-mapview

I'm going to show a google map in Xamarin.Android application. Consider that I have only one Activity (empty) and I draw every other thing (list , labels , buttons and ...) inside that and I can't use fragments. 
 for this, I have a class that inherit from Android.Gms.Maps.MapView and override GetMapAsync as you can see in code. But I don't know how can I call that for creating MapObject.

```
 public class AndroidMapView : MapView
{
    private GoogleMap gMap;

    public AndroidMapView() : base(Renderer.Context)
    {

    }

    public override void GetMapAsync(IOnMapReadyCallback callback)
    {
        var options = new GoogleMapOptions();
    }

}

public class MyOnMapReady : Java.Lang.Object, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    public GoogleMap Map { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler MapReady;

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        Map = googleMap;
        var handler = MapReady;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In my IOS version,I inherit from MKMapView and it shows that map for me. Do you have any Idea how can I do that in Xamarin.Android without using Fragments or adding extra Activity. just simply by inheriting MapView?

Comment: Why cant you use a fragment in a activity that contains a list and a label? o0

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe, everything adds to the activity programmatically and my only activity uses for all form (It's a framework that we develop not a simple app). so our activity is always empty without any fragment. Is using fragment mandatory for GoogleMap?

Comment: It isn't necessary to use a Fragment, but it makes it much easier. You can add the Fragment programatically too...

Comment: @Cheesebaron how can I add fragment programmatically without touching layout xml?